# Javascript - get neighbor cells in a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKYlikFAV4k&t=1848s&ab_channel=TheCodingTrain

However, I'm using vanilla Javascript. I'm struggling to get the neighboring cells for each cell in my grid. I'm pretty new to coding so help would be very much appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```js
//GLOBAL VARIABLES 
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const wh = 600;
const cellSize = 30;
const rows = 20;
const cols = 20;
const grid = new Array(rows);
const open = [];
const closed = [];
let start;
let end;

//FUNCTIONS 
//Immediately-invoked function expression
//Runs code immediately when the page loads and keeps it out of the global scope (avoids naming conflicts)
(function() {
  setup();
})();

function Cell(x, y) { //Constructor function for each cell in the array
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.f = 0;
  this.g = 0;
  this.h = 0;
  this.show = function(color) { //Function to show cell on grid 
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, cellSize, cellSize);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, cellSize, cellSize);
  }
}

//Function to setup the canvas 
function setup() {
  let interval = setInterval(update, 120);
  canvas.setAttribute('width', wh);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', wh);
  document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]); //Inserts canvas before the first element in body 
  createGrid();
  setStartEnd();
}

//Function to create grid 
function createGrid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //Creating 2D array
    grid[i] = new Array(cols);
  }
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //Creating a new cell for each spot in the array
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = new Cell();
      grid[i][j].x = x;
      grid[i][j].y = y;
      grid[i][j].show();
      x = x + 1 * 30;
    }
    x = 0;
    y = y + 1 * 30;
  }
}

//Function that defines the start and end points
function setStartEnd() {
  start = grid[0][0];
  end = grid[cols - 1][rows - 1];
  open.push(start);
}

//Function to remove a node from an array
function removeArray(arr, e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === e) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

//Main function
function update() {
  //nodes part of "open" array are green 
  for (let i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {
    open[i].show('green');
  }

  //nodes part of "closed" array are red
  for (let i = 0; i < closed.length; i++) {
    closed[i].show('red');
  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem in your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made it a bit hard for yourself by having `Cell` not store its own `x,y` position in the grid.

If you move some logic from your nested `i,j` for loop to your `Cell` class, it gets easier. I modified `Cell` to store its `x` and `y` grid coordinate rather than pixel coordinate. You can then, in `update`, do something like this:

```
  const nextOpenSet = new Set();
  open.forEach(cell => {
    const above = grid[cell.y - 1]?.[cell.x];
    if (above) nextOpenSet.add(above);
    
    const below = grid[cell.y + 1]?.[cell.x];
    if (below) nextOpenSet.add(below);
    
    const left = grid[cell.y][cell.x - 1];
    if (left) nextOpenSet.add(left);
    
    const right = grid[cell.y][cell.x + 1];
    if (right) nextOpenSet.add(right);
  });
  
  open = Array.from(nextOpenSet);
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
//GLOBAL VARIABLES 
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const wh = 600;
const cellSize = 30;
const rows = 20;
const cols = 20;
const grid = new Array(rows);
let open = [];
const closed = [];
let start;
let end;

//FUNCTIONS 
//Immediately-invoked function expression
//Runs code immediately when the page loads and keeps it out of the global scope (avoids naming conflicts)
(function() {
  setup();
})();

function Cell(x, y) { //Constructor function for each cell in the array
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.show = function(color) { //Function to show cell on grid 
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x * cellSize, this.y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x * cellSize, this.y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
  }
}

//Function to setup the canvas 
function setup() {
  let interval = setInterval(update, 120);
  canvas.setAttribute('width', wh);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', wh);
  document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]); //Inserts canvas before the first element in body 
  createGrid();
  setStartEnd();
}

//Function to create grid 
function createGrid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //Creating 2D array
    grid[i] = new Array(cols);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //Creating a new cell for each spot in the array
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
      grid[i][j].show();
    }
  }
}

//Function that defines the start and end points
function setStartEnd() {
  start = grid[0][0];
  end = grid[cols - 1][rows - 1];
  open.push(start);
}

//Function to remove a node from an array
function removeArray(arr, e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === e) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

//Main function
function update() {
  //nodes part of "open" array are green 
  for (let i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {
    open[i].show('green');
  }

  //nodes part of "closed" array are red
  for (let i = 0; i < closed.length; i++) {
    closed[i].show('red');
  }
  
  const nextOpenSet = new Set();
  open.forEach(cell => {
    const above = grid[cell.y - 1]?.[cell.x];
    if (above) nextOpenSet.add(above);
    
    const below = grid[cell.y + 1]?.[cell.x];
    if (below) nextOpenSet.add(below);
    
    const left = grid[cell.y][cell.x - 1];
    if (left) nextOpenSet.add(left);
    
    const right = grid[cell.y][cell.x + 1];
    if (right) nextOpenSet.add(right);
  });
  
  open = Array.from(nextOpenSet);
  
}
```